# Sensitivity Analysis of Statistical Model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model

Suppose I had built a model that predicts the likelihood of whether a sales agent will make a sale during an interaction with any given customer. The model is based on many variables, one of which is the 'friendliness' of the sales agent.

I run my model over my sales team of 100 staff, 50 of which have been considered 'friendly' staff (and 50 unfriendly), and I can predict the number of sales for the month.

If I were to fire the 50 'unfriendly' staff and hire 50 'friendly' staff (making a total team of 100 friendly staff), how I can I use my sales model to predict the uplift in my sales for the month with 100% friendly sales staff?

Would it be a matter of understanding (quantifying) the impact of the friendliness of staff and using that in a way to approximate the uplift in sales?

Comment: What type of model have you built? Logistic regression? Are you using R or Excel or something else?

Comment: Haven't built it yet. If it were GLM in R, how would you utilise the `summary()` of the GLM?

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Comment: Any recommendation on a better title for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions are below. Say we've run our GLM in R and called it `fit`, i.e. we've done `fit <- glm(...)`.

`predict(fit,newdata,type = "response")` will get you the predicted probabilities for a new $X$ matrix, i.e. for a new workforce with attributes given by the rows of $X$.

Now we just need to decide how we're going to construct our `newdata` matrix.

The first 50 rows are easy -- they're just the rows corresponding to the friendly staff in our original matrix/data frame.

For the remaining 50, we need to make some (hopefully sensible) decisions.

We know that we want the friendliness column to be all `1`s, but we're also going to need to provide the other attributes for these new employees. One way would be to assign the mean of each attribute from the original data frame to each new employee. This essentially means we're saying that all new employees are completely average, apart from the fact they're all friendly; i.e. we're looking at the marginal effect of making everybody friendly. We could also use the average among friendly staff if you expect some correlations between friendliness and other attributes.

Another option would be to try some sort of sampling procedure, whereby we get lots of possible outcomes corresponding to different attribute assignments, and we can look at the **distribution** of expected sales under the assumptions we embed in our sampling procedure.

The simplest way to do this would be bootstrapping -- sample attributes *with replacement* from the original matrix and use these samples to create 50 plausible new (friendly) employees. Predict the outcome using this new matrix and store the result. Rinse and repeat 500-1000 times, plot the histogram of your expected sales figures to get a sense of the possible variability/uncertainty associated with your decision to replace all unfriendly staff with friendly staff.